# Extract hour and minute not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to extrac the hour and minute from a date of the format

```
2012/12/01 02:03:44
```

my code looks smth like

```
SELECT to_char(t.start_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                              AS Start_DATE, 
       to_char(t.resolved_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                           AS Closed_DATE, 
       extract(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(t.start_date, 'YYYY/MON/DD HH24:MI:SS'))  AS Start_DATE_min,
       extract(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(t.closed_date, 'YYYY/MON/DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS Closed_DATE_min,
       extract(HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(t.start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))    AS Start_DATE_h, 
       extract(HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(t.closed_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))   AS Closed_DATE_h 
FROM   t
```

But in the extract fields I just get 0s.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT to_char(t.start_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                              AS Start_DATE, 
       to_char(t.resolved_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                           as closed_date, 
       extract(minute from cast(t.start_date as timestamp))  as start_date_min,
       extract(MINUTE FROM cast(t.closed_date as timestamp)) AS Closed_DATE_min,
       extract(HOUR FROM cast(t.start_date as timestamp))    AS Start_DATE_h, 
       extract(HOUR FROM cast(t.closed_date as timestamp))   AS Closed_DATE_h 
FROM   t 



SELECT to_char(t.start_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                              AS Start_DATE, 
       to_char(t.resolved_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                           as closed_date, 
       to_char(t.start_date, 'MI')  as start_date_min,
       to_char(t.closed_date, 'MI') as closed_date_min,
       to_char(t.start_date, 'HH24')    as start_date_h, 
       to_char(t.closed_date, 'HH24')   AS Closed_DATE_h 
FROM   t
```

The problem with your code:
TO_TIMESTAMP(t.start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - the first argument is char so Oracle converts datetime column "start_date" to char using session NLS settings. It may differ from your mask 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT to_char(t.start_date,    'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                AS Start_DATE, 
       to_char(t.resolved_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                AS Closed_DATE, 
       extract(MINUTE FROM t.start_date  ) AS Start_DATE_min,
       extract(MINUTE FROM t.closed_date ) AS Closed_DATE_min,
       extract(HOUR   FROM t.start_date  ) AS Start_DATE_h, 
       extract(HOUR   FROM t.closed_date ) AS Closed_DATE_h 
FROM   t
```

I assume that you are storing Dates using datetime format and you do not need to transform them to timestamp.

**UPDATE**: If you have a DATE type there is no point in extracting minute and hour information from a type that does not have this information. **It explains why you are reading zeros** Change the data type to DATETIME. It is like extracting decimals from an INTEGER. Or just put the zeros and save CPU:

> ```
> SELECT to_char(t.start_date,    'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                AS Start_DATE, 
>        to_char(t.resolved_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')                AS Closed_DATE, 
>        0 AS Start_DATE_min,
>        0 AS Closed_DATE_min,
>        0 AS Start_DATE_h, 
>        0 AS Closed_DATE_h 
> FROM   t
> ```

P.S. In the question it says: "I'm trying to extrac the hour and minute from a date of the format
2012/12/01 02:03:44". How can you store this in a DATE without loosing the time information?

Comment: if start_date and closed_date have DATE type you cannot extract time from them regarding ANSI SQL!

Comment: Well then that's OP's problem, that's why he would receive all 0s, if they're stored as `DATE`, right?

Comment: @McAdam331 I think that's the problem of the answer because it won't even run if start_date and closed_date have DATE type

Comment: Then I think @borjab should edit to suggest to OP that he use `datetime` instead.

Comment: Plus. If you want to cast Date as timestamp use a cast. But do not change it to string and then to timestamp.

Comment: @borjab please read Oracle reference. You cannot extract TIME from DATE, but you can extract YEAR, MONTH, DAY